# How do I make a Decal look worn?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, transparency, procedural

[image]I have what seems like a simple example here.  I wanted to practice texture and lighting by making some simple M&M renders.  I used a NOISE texture for the surface to give it some "eggshell" quality in the render, I am progressing nicely.  Now I'm stuck...

I created the "M" logo as a PNG with alpha channel.  I applied it in the material using the image texture with mapping node and texture coordinates.  All basic stuff so far.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to use procedural nodes like Voronoi or Noise to make the stark white of the M Logo look "worn" so some of the color of the M&M show through, like it's scuffed.  Now the render isn't convincing because every M is too perfect.  I know I could use my image editing software to make some alpha transparencies in the PNG decal, but then they would be the same across all meshes, and I was hoping to use a NOISE node to randomize it a bit.

Can't I use a NOISE tesxture to a COLOR RAMP then make one of the colors ALPHA transparent thus having the M logo "Fade" and let the color show through?  I think I've tried 100 different things and I am not getting it.  (I am not a Blender expert but have an intermediate understanding of texture node setups...)

Here's a link to my .blend file in my dropbox, without ANY treatment on the M logo.  You can see they are too stark white and perfect.  I want to scuff just the logo up.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!  (Render is formatted for dual monitors so please ignore the odd render dimensions!)

[Blend File in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo933f63ygc5zaa/2018%20MAR%20MM%20Wood%20Flooring.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are using the alpha channel as a mask to control the mix of different elements, you need to make the mask less perfect. Instead of being a perfect white mask, you need to subtract from the white using a texture. Why subtract? Think of white as 1 and Black as 0. You want to affect the mask without adding any more information to the black areas.

[image]

Subtract a texture from the alpha channel, and use the result as a Mask to control the mix for the color for the shader.

[image]

Combining other textures and subtracting them from the alpha you can further distress a texture to seem more random.

[image]

Comment: Wow incredible!  I'm sad that I spent an hour using "node logic" to try to connect nodes in such a way that I could achieve this effect, and came up with nothing.  What you showed here is exactly what I was looking for but I would never have arrived there with my knowledge of nodes.  Looks like I just need to keep practicing and learning from people like you.  Thanks so much for the time.