# Showing a mesh through a textur

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, node-editor

A few weeks ago i’ve drawn a new character. Excited by her design i thought to make her in 3D. Before starting tho i noticed an issue. You see the body of the character have a special feature. Through her body, in fact, it’s possible to see some spheres, called Cores.

[image: The cores inside my character's body]
So my issue is to recreate this same effect or something similar to it. I thought to create some spheres to put inside the model. But then i thought “How can i make them see though the model?” I thought about using the transparency with the Node editor or something like that, but then i would see the objects and the background behind her and, as you can see from the picture, you can’t see, for example, the back of her hair or the rest of the cloak. The only things you can see are the Cores and the Eyebrows.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your model, current material nodes and image textures.

Comment: I didn't started the model neither the material nodes and textures yet. Before doing that i wanted to had ideas on how to create that particular effect.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. It seems to me that what you need is to create masks that control how the textures are mixed. The core principles are outlined here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104373/how-do-i-make-a-decal-look-worn/104379#104379

Comment: I see, I'll take a look at the principles and see what i can do

Comment: Stack exchange doesn't really work well for theoretical questions. You should start making your model, and get back here when you have a concrete issue or hit a part you can't solve.