# How to make a grainy material in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

How can I make a grainy/noisy looking material in Blender Cycles?  I want to have a node set up where I can create a grainy material of my choice of color, with a noise variable so that I change the level of grain shown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a noise texture. You can change the scale and detail. Hooking it up to a Color Ramp (or curve, or gamma or Bright/Contrast) node will allow you to set the contrast  [image]

You can set the color directly.

[image]

Or use the texture to control the mix of other colors.

[image]

Or different shaders.

[image]

Or you can use it to combine with other textures and types of noise, as described in this answer: [How do I make a Decal look worn?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104373/how-do-i-make-a-decal-look-worn/104379#104379)

[image]